# Polymer core-ajax : php not found

Tags: ajax, polymer

i create polymer element(w/core-ajax) to post data to php file.i got this error it seems like the data cannot be sent to the php file.

Did this error has something to do with my server?I setup my project using yeoman+polymer generator.
this is my error : "Cannot POST /elements/register-el/register.php"
http://s1.postimg.org/4c7dmgs1r/ask1.png

register-el.html

```
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/polymer/polymer.html">
<link rel="import" href="../../bower_components/core-ajax/core-ajax.html">
<polymer-element name="register-el" attributes="">
  <template>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="register-el.css">
    <div class="body-reg">
          <paper-input-decorator class="custom" label="First Name" floatingLabel autoValidate error="Firstname is required!">
              <input is="core-input" type="text" value="{{fname}}" id="fname" required>
          </paper-input-decorator>


          <paper-input-decorator class="custom"label="Last Name" floatingLabel autoValidate error="Lastname is required!">
              <input is="core-input"  type="text" value="{{lname}}" id="lname" required>
          </paper-input-decorator>

          <paper-input-decorator class="custom" label="Email" floatingLabel error="Email is required!" autoValidate>
              <input is="core-input" required type="email" id="email" value="{{email}}">
          </paper-input-decorator>

          <paper-input-decorator class="custom" label="Password" floatingLabel error="Must contain 8 or more characters that are of at least one number, and one uppercase and lowercase letter" autoValidate>
              <input is="core-input" value="{{pwd}}" id="password" type="password" name="pwd1" required pattern="(?=.*\d)(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{8,}">
          </paper-input-decorator>

          <paper-input-decorator class="custom" label="Re-type Password" floatingLabel error="input is required!" autoValidate>
              <input is="core-input" value="{{cpwd}}" id="confirm_password" type="password" required pattern="{{pwd}}">
          </paper-input-decorator>


           <paper-button raised on-click="{{submit}}">
            <core-icon icon="done"></core-icon>
            Register
          </paper-button>
            <paper-toast id="donereg" text="Your have been registered!Go to login page">
                <div style="color: #E9E88B" on-click="{{gotologin}}" id="gotolog">LOGIN</div>
            </paper-toast>
          <core-ajax
          id="ajaxsubmit"

            url="elements/register-el/register.php"
            method='POST'
            headers='{"X-Requested-With": "XMLHttpRequest"}'
            params='{"firstname":"{{fname}}","lastname":"{{lname}}","email":"{{email}}","password":"{{cpwd}}"}'
            response="{{response}}"></core-ajax>
          </div>
  </template>
  <script>
    (function () {
      Polymer({

      submit: function () {
          if (this.$.confirm_password.validity.valid && this.$.password.validity.valid && this.$.email.validity.valid && this.$.fname.validity.valid && this.$.lname.validity.valid) {
              console.log("Right!");
              this.$.donereg.show();
              this.$.ajaxsubmit.go();
          }
          else{
            console.log("Error");
            console.log(this.fname);

          }
        },
       gotologin : function () {
        document.querySelector('app-router').go('/login');
        },
        responseChanged : function (oldvalue) {
          console.log(this.response);
        }

      });

    })();
  </script>
</polymer-element>
```

Answer (score 0):

A path never start with a slash use "./" or remove it.

Comment: in you're import replace antislach by slash

Comment: And you're folder elements is on roots of you're project?

Comment: So it's may a permissions problem